# Can reading a continuously appended file cause issues?

Tags: c#, file, text, stream

We have log files on another server that are created and continuously appended with status and error logs using:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
}
```

These are on a remote Windows machine and we usually go through the tedious process of connecting remotely and reading the files through notepad. So I was thinking of creating an application to either copy the files locally (using something like `File.Copy()`) or view the files' current snapshot or line-by-line (using something like `FileInfo(path).OpenText().ReadLine()` or `.ReadToEnd()`).

My question is, can there be an issue or a conflict that can cause an exception with the running logger if I do any of these reads? The loggers are integrated into the main service application and I wouldn't want to crash our service because of reading a log file.

Comment: _"Insufficient data for meaningful answer"_  - Isaac Asimov. Will need more code, particularly on how you intend to read the log

Comment: Thanks for the refreshing reference :). I didn't know which way to go yet with the code so I was wishing for an answer that would lead me to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it should be "fine", for certain meanings of "fine".

The `StreamWriter` returned by `File.AppendText()` opens the file with `FileShare.Read`, which allows other processes to read the file even though it's open for writing. On your polling end, you'll need to make sure you open the file with `FileShare.Write`, to allow other processes (e.g. the logging process) to open the file even if you already have it open for reading.

Of course, you may wind up reading partial data now and then. So I guess it depends somewhat on your definition of "conflict". :) But it should be possible to at least get it to work without causing the logger to throw an exception.

Comment: Awesome answer! Totally fine with the partial data :). Just don't want my colleagues to tackle me if I crash the service with my puny log scraper app

Comment: @Tyress: just to be clear: lacking a code example, I can't verify to be 100% sure everything is implemented exactly as assumed. Just as any new code should be tested, you should of course test your "puny log scraper app" against an offline version of the service, just to make sure it works as expected. Wouldn't want anyone getting tackled. :)